# Большое количество ошибок после клонирование проекта

Tags: c++, github, visual-studio-2017

Клонировал на ноутбук проект. В репозитории хранятся следующие файлы: .sln, .h, .cpp, .vcxproj, .vcxproj.filters, и .gitignore. После клонирование открываю проект и он не компилируется по причине ошибок (500+ ошибок: E1696,E0282,E0260,E0020 и еще множество). Видимо из-за отсутствия различных файлов, который заигнорены были при PUSH'е у меня такое количество ошибок. Как исправить такое множество ошибок?

(MVS Community 2017 C++).

Comment: Приведите текст ошибок. Еще проверьте, установлен ли в системе тулсет, используемый в проекте.

Comment: @VTT Тулсет? SDK? Установил, надо указать путь к нему? Пример ошибки: 
Ошибка (активно) E1696 не удается открыть источник файл "float.h" \ E0282 глобальная область видимости не содержит "fmodf" \

Comment: @VTT Ошибка MSB8036 не удалось найти Windows SDK версии 10.0.16299.0. Установите нужную версию Windows SDK или измените версию SDK на страницах свойств проекта либо щелкнув правой кнопкой мыши решение и выбрав "Изменить целевую платформу решения". Скачал SDK, надо как-то показать вижуалке путь к SDK?

Answer (score 2):

Пункт меню "Средства" -> "Получить средства и компоненты". В появившемся окне находите "Разработка классических приложений на C++", где ставите галочку на пункте с требуемым SDK.

Comment: Вот у меня та же проблема, причем пакет SDK скачан. Я просто исходный код расположил не в папке проекта, мне так удобнее, но получаю 572 ошибки, из которых, видимо реальная только "не удалось найти Windows SDK", который установлен. И вот вопрос, как это правится

Answer (score 0):

Выбери по новой "версия пакета SDK для Windows", также попробуй выбрать "набор инструментов платформы".
В моем случае первый параметр был 10.0, выбрал из списка 10.0.17134.0(был скачан он и ещё один).
Второй параметр был выбран VS 2017 (v142), выбрал VS 2017(v141).
После все заработало. Изначально показывало также 700+ ошибок.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).